# Uploading video on youtube by android app using java

Tags: java, android, video, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am working on an app where I need to upload videos(by some users) on my youtube channel which will be later played by the app users.

There is no detailed explanation of uploading videos(on youtube) at it's official documentation.

> How to upload video on my youtube channel from android app using java?

Thank You

Comment: did you find a way to upload to your own channel ?

Answer (score 1):

There is actually an example of this on official pages [Youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert#examples).

Your job would be just to adjust it for Android.

Comment: What to add in build.gradle of my app as dependency for youtube api?

Answer (score 1):

Letting other people upload random videos to your channel is not recommended. That's why OAuth2 only lets them to upload to their own channel. You can use YouTube Direct Lite for people to upload to their channel, but you can still collect those videos into your playlist.

https://code.google.com/p/youtube-direct-lite/

https://github.com/youtube/yt-direct-lite-iOS

https://github.com/youtube/yt-direct-lite-android